# .net sockets data transmition using sockets (c#)

Tags: c#, android, .net, sockets, networkstream

I'm trying to transfer some data between android client and .net server.
I used sockets. the client sockets is connected while in the server I get no response. 
can anyone please review this code and help me? I'm kind of lost.

**my client code:**

```
Socket socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            try 
            { 
                socket1.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(string_ip), 8080); 
                if (socket1.Connected) 
                { 
                    Log("connected");
                    NetworkStream networkStream1 = new NetworkStream(socket1);
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                    byte[] recievedData = new byte[1024];
                    string message = "alon aviv";
                    sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    networkStream1.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                } 
                else 
                { Log("not connected"); } 
            }
```

**my server code:**

```
Socket socket1 = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint ipEnd = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(string_ip), 8080);
                socket1.Bind(ipEnd);
                socket1.Listen(1);
                socket1.Accept();
                if (socket1.Connected)
                {
                    UpdateLogText("socket connected");
                    NetworkStream networkStream1 = new NetworkStream(socket1);
                    byte[] recievedData = new byte[1024];
                    networkStream1.Read(recievedData, 0, recievedData.Length);
                    string message_recieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recievedData);
                    UpdateLogText(message_recieved);
                }
```

Comment: Is the listening port open through firewall?

Answer (score 1):

I also tested your code and it was not working at my side as well. I made some adjustments which do work. Please try:

Client

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

   Socket socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
   try
   {
    socket1.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
    if (socket1.Connected)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Connected");



     // Encode the data string into a byte array.
     byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

     // Send the data through the socket.
     int bytesSent = socket1.Send(msg);

     // Receive the response from the remote device.
     int bytesRec = socket1.Receive(bytes);
     Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

     // Release the socket.
     socket1.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
     socket1.Close();
    }
    else
    {
     Console.WriteLine("not connected");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Server

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 class Program
 {
  public static string data = null;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

   byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

   Socket socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
   System.Net.IPEndPoint ipEnd = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
   

   // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
   // listen for incoming connections.
   try
   {
    socket1.Bind(ipEnd);
    socket1.Listen(10);

    // Start listening for connections.
    while (true)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
     // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
     Socket handler = socket1.Accept();
     data = null;

     // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
     while (true)
     {
      bytes = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
      data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
      if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
      {
       break;
      }
     }

     // Show the data on the console.
     Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

     // Echo the data back to the client.
     byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

     handler.Send(msg);
     handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
     handler.Close();
    }

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
   }

   Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }
}
```